# UICollectionviewCell image change on selction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UICollectionview` controller with `UIButton` in each cell. On selecting the the button I have to change the button bg image, on double-tap I have to again change it. (Single tap to like, double-tap to love concept on user interest page). 
What is the best way to do this?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [interestsCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton* img=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [img addTarget: self action: @selector(interestClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;
    img.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 60);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];

    UILabel* lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, 80, 20)];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.text=[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11];
    lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:135.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:135.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented this method?
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}

Comment: Yes, I have that method but how to change the selected cells's subiviews(button's) background on selection?

Comment: -(void)interestClicked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    //Change button image here
    [collectionView reloadData];
}

Answer (score 1):

You can handle such situation with single and double `TapGesture`. with help of respected selector, you can change `UIImage` of `UIButton`.

Here are the link that guide you. how to create double Tap Gesture on `UICollectionView`. with help of this you can created single Tap gesture as well.

[Collection View + Double Tap Gesture](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/09/28/collection-view-default-gestures.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your button and change color as you want.

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTwice:)];

  tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

  //stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
  [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];

  [self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce]; //remove the other button action which calls method `button`
  [self.button addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
```